# Is a CRUD application always an API in the web world?

Tags: rest, soap, crud

Since in about 99.9% of tutorials, posts and forums, whenever the word CRUD gets in stage, the word "API" immediately follows it, I wasn't able to find the answer to my doubt: **Is every web application with full CRUD functionality an API?** or **can I actually code a CRUD web application that's not considered an API?**

All these doubts make me wonder of the early days of web development, where people would use the front end to send requests to a server, then the server would create/query/modify/delete DBs/files based on a specific (let's say) button being clicked...were those still called "CRUD APIs"?

Or **is a CRUD only an API when there's no direct calling of the model's methods?** (it needs, let's say, a controller code that'll ensure that the correct input and request have been made before sending the instructions to the model that'll actually do the CRUD work)

Answer (score 1):

CRUD refers very generically to Create, Read, Update, and Delete patterns and any application architecture can implement CRUD. API is also a very generic acronym and doesn't imply anything about what functionalities must be present. You could have an API that only provides home addresses (read-only) by state, zip, street, etc. and thus enable developers to use it for address verification. Even without a way to delete, update, or create, it's still an API.